# How to check that user enter a valid english word in javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am going to make a game in javascript , in which i will gives user a option to select given characters and make a valid english word , now the question is that how can i check in javascript that what user enters is a valid english word or not , suppose 
i give user following letters

1. O
2. D
3. O
4. G

Now possibly he can make three words from these characters `God`, `Good` or `Dog` .

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

what about this guys

[Typo.JS](http://www.chrisfinke.com/2011/03/31/announcing-typo-js-client-side-javascript-spellchecking/)

Is this a good way to do so or not ?

Comment: You need some kind of word dictionary - either one you maintain yourself, or find an existing web-dictionary which exposes an API you can call.

Comment: This requires a dictionary of words, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166206/javascript-spell-checking-methods

Comment: You forgot `Goo`, `Do`, and `Go`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He could also conceivably write `DO` and `GO`. You need to use a dictionary of the allowed words, and check the answer against that.

```
var allowedWords = ['god','good','dog','do','go'];
var enteredWord = 'GOD';

if(allowedWords.indexOf(enteredWord.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
   // match
}
```

Comment: well if i consider `do` as valid or anything which is legal then what ? in that case i have to make my own dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Here you have english word MySql database.
http://androidtech.com/html/wordnet-mysql-20.php

Now you need to implement server-side functionality.Will return true or false when word not exist.
You can call service by Ajax using Jquery and check words in your game.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/

Look for Client side solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple questions, you can also validate the answer like this:

```
var gameDict = [
    { 'letters':['o','d','o','g'],  'words':['god','good','dog','do','go', 'goo']},
    { 'letters':['a','e','p'],      'words':['ape']},
    { 'letters':['p','n','e','t'],  'words':['pen', 'ten', 'net']}
]

// Returns `true` if the answer is valid, `false` if it's not.
function validateAnswer(questionNumber, answer){
    return gameDict[questionNumber].words.indexOf(answer.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}

console.log(validateAnswer(0,'Good'));
// true
console.log(validateAnswer(1,'ap'));
// false
```

But yes, you will have to manually write a dictionary for your game, since aside from checking if the word is actually a English word, you will also have to check if your characters can make that word.

Answer (score 0):

As Thor suggested you need a dictionary (an array of strings that are the words you consider valid "english words").

But if you really want to check the input **against any english word the "English Dictionary"** the array of words would be **realy** huge and, as it would be loaded along the Javascript, the Javascript would become a file too big to download along with your web page.

In that case, you'd need a database (let say MySQL) to store the words and a script that runs on the server (let's say PHP) that you pass the word with an ajax call. The script would make a query on the DB to see if the word exists and give back the result to your javascript as the ajax response (1=english word  0=word not on the dictionary)