# Open Source Spell Check for javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spell-checking

I am stuck with spell check and dictionary issues. basically I am looking for a spell check solution. It could be open source or licensed.
I have already tried typo.js from https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/.

My requirement is given below -

1. It has to check the spelling of the word, for wrong words it should be red as showed in browsers.
2. There should be an options to add the word to dictionary. I have tried the same with typo.js I can find the spell check suggestions but could not add the same to dictionary.
3. How to disable browser's spell check.

Also It should support Linux servers.

Comment: Do you wan't spell check or also with suggestions? Here's another question with some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166206/javascript-spell-checking-methods

Comment: Thanks Bart, I have tried the same. But I want to add into dictionary as well, there only I stuck.
Also here the demo link http://www.chrisfinke.com/files/typo-demo/
here if you type Monday then it spell correct but when you tried for monday it will give options "noonday, monody, monad, moray, money"

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your question and the reason why you decided not to go for Typo.js (answer on my comment), I decided to look at the Typo.js project.

If you look at the GitHub test folder of Typo.js, you can see that there is a way to include custom dictionaries (different languages etc):
https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/tree/master/tests

Using a custom dictionary is very easy:

```
var dictionary = new Typo("en_EN", false, false, { dictionaryPath: "typo/dictionaries" });
```

Here you can find the directory structure: https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/tree/master/tests/dictionaries

Now all you need is an open source English dictionary which does have all these words, and include this into the Typo library :)

Comment: I am looking for the solutions where I can suggest to add to dictionary :)
Thanks for custom dictionary part.

Comment: And it's not a possibility to alter the dictionary file?